# Translation of lmino and lminaihu

Tags: words, parashat-shemini

In Parshat Shmini ([Vayikro 11:22](http://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.11.22?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)), the Torah uses two different words for "species" in listing species of kosher insects:

> "אֶת־הָֽאַרְבֶּה **לְמִינוֹ** וְאֶת־הַסָּלְעָם **לְמִינֵהוּ**"

What is the difference in translation between the two words?

I am aware of the N'ziv in Haamek Davar but not satisfied with his answer.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya nevcomer

Comment: Newcomer, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your questions here! Please take a look at how I edited your question post to be a bit more clear. The more clearly questions are posed, the better chance they have of getting good answers, and the more valuable they are to the reading public. As @Danno rightly points out, this question has already be posed here, so this post will likely be marked as a duplicate of that one. Your version of the question adds value by providing a different set of words that searchers may use to find the question; thanks again!

Comment: I will give my answer on the duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Is there really a question?
A simple idea by example (from ornithology, [passerines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passerine)). crow --> an Order, Crow and his specie (corvus albicolis, corvus corax, etc).
Passerine birds with many suborders (למינהו) as suborder passery, infraorder corvida

#### An order that has not suborders --> למינו

#### An order that has suborders --> למינהו

Arbe is one order without suborders
 Sal'am is an order with suborders.

 Additionnal remark, the word סוג is introduced by Yehuda Ibn Tibbon and is not used as super species or super order in Tora and Chazal. It is in Chazal a big container (see Dmay 5, 6:פרק ה - משנה ו

הַלּוֹקֵחַ מִן הַסִּיטוֹן וְחָזַר וְלָקַח מִמֶּנּוּ שְׁנִיָּה, לֹא יְעַשֵּׂר מִזֶּה עַל זֶה, אֲפִלּוּ מֵאוֹתוֹ הַסּוּג, אֲפִלּוּ מֵאוֹתוֹ הַמִּין. נֶאֱמָן הַסִּיטוֹן לוֹמַר, מִשֶּׁל אֶחָד הֵם: & rlm;

See [here](http://eol.org/pages/6580/overview) and [here](http://eol.org/pages/606826/overview)

it is as leminam and leminehem. עושם באימה רצון קונם עושים באימה רצון קוניהם are 2 girsaot of kel adon and I think that who say konam is because of the difference between למינם למינהם and the cholek think that if there is elokim and baalim we need to save a plural i.e. konim instead of kone. anyway minehu = המינים שלו and למינם is כל אחד עם המין שלו.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses thanks to you I understand and answered the question

Comment: it is as leminam and leminehem. עושם באימה רצון קונם עושים באימה רצון קוניהם are 2 girsaot of kel adon and I think that who say konam is because of the difference between     למינם למינהם and the cholek think that if there is elokim and baalim we need to save a plural i.e. konim instead of kone. anyway minehu = המינים שלו and למינם is  כל אחד עם המין שלו. @mevaqesh